Why does my Powershell variable not get set as expected when executing inline powershell in yaml task: AzureCLI@2?
Below errors occur when executing a DevOps pipeline using Yaml AzureCLI@2 task.

ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
ERROR: argument --assignee-object-id: expected one argument

task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Assign role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" to the task-poll-queued-compliance-jobs1-<env> logic app'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.connectionName }}
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    inlineScript: '$assigneeId = (az ad sp list --all --filter "servicePrincipalType eq ''ManagedIdentity'' and displayName eq ''<logic app name>''" | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty id);az role assignment create --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" --assignee-object-id $assigneeId --scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccount>"'

I have tried the following to diagnose and fix the issue.

I have hard coded the $assigneeId value in the YAML and executed the pipeline successfully.

EG. az role assignment create --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" --assignee-object-id "" --scope "/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/"'

On failed pipeline runs I am able copy the inline script to be executed from the Pipeline logs and run it in an Azure Cloud shell with no issues.

I tried giving the App Registration that the pipeline connects to Azure has owner role of the resource group, but this also did not fix the issue.



Hi Dean! I assume that your Pipeline is using a Service Connection that is connected to a service principle in Entra ID. Can you verify that this Service Principle have access to perform the "az ad sp list" command?

According to the current info, it seems that the App Registration used in your service connection doesn't have enough permission to list SP. You can try to assign it with 'Application Administrator' role of your Azure tenant.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT happy to  give App Admin for short term testing but is there a more granular role that it can be assigned to for the long term?

thanks @EricQvarnström, do you have any suggestions on how to test the service connection has access to az ad sp list?

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT confirmed, giving the app registration the Application Administrator role solved the problem.

Hi @Dean, it's great to know that assigning your SP with the Application Administrator role can solve the problem. "is there a more granular role that it can be assigned to for the long term" - In addition to the “Application Administrator“ role, you can assign API permission Application.Read.All. See my answer below for the details.

Hi @Dean, have you checked the update below to assign your app registration with API permission Application.Read.All? Did it work for you?

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT unfortunately assigning the Application.Read.All on the app registration did not solve the issue.

@Dean, have you Grant admin consent for your tenant? Testing on my side, after getting Application.Read.All permission, the app registration is able to run az ad sp list.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT admin consent was granted

@Dean, is your managed identity system-assigned or user-assigned?

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT the managed identity is system assigned.

Hi @Dean, I have tested assigning a system-assigned managed identity (created in a logic app) roles using an application having API permission Application.Read.All and Owner role of the resource group, it works fine. You can check whether you assigned API permission Application.Read.All to the correct application.

Root Cause
According to the current info, the App Registration used in your service connection doesn't have enough permission to list SP.
Solution
Option1: Assign the App Registration used in your service connection with 'Application Administrator' role of your Azure tenant.
Option2: Assign the App Registration used in your service connection with API permission Application.Read.All.
Go to your App Registration -> API permissions -> Add a permission -> Microsoft Graph -> Application permissions -> Application -> Application.Read.All -> Grant admin consent for your tenant.


Result:

